# Why does php header() acts weird if the page is bookmarked?

Tags: php

I wrote a php code. The addressbar acts mysteriously. Can anyone explain what is happening.

index.php

```
<?php
/* Notes:
 * $_COOKIE['user_id'] is set and alive
 * $_SESSION['user_id'] does not exist
 * session_start() is given already
 */
...
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id') && isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    $location = 'Location:http://localhost/project/login.php';
    header($location);
}
?>
```

In address bar I type "localhost/project/index.php". It works fine.

I bookmarked "localhost/project/index.php" and this time I used the bookmark to go to the index.php. I expect to be redirected to "localhost/project/login.php"

however the browser redirect me to "localhost/project/project/login.php"

Can anyone explain this phenomenon to me?

Thanks

Comment: This is your full script? Do you have rewrite rules in place? Have you commented out the `header` to confirm you enter that condition?

Comment: Hi Chris85,
The problem is just from this if() statement. As I mentioned, $_SESSION['user_id'] died. $_COOKIE['user_id'] still exists and it's alive.
What do you mean by commenting the header??

Comment: `/*header($location);*/ die("we're conditioning");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chris85,
Thanks for the reply.
I found the problem. It was a simple coding error which unfortunately took long time to find.

That's how my actual code was:

```
<?php
define('HOST',"http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/project");

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id') && isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    $location = 'Location:'.HOST.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header($location);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Unfortunately, by mistake I added $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] which I did not think of it at all that once the $location is being assigned the project would be repeated:

```
<?php
echo $location;
/*Output: http://localhost/project*/
?>
```

By removing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] the problem solved:

```
<?php
echo $location;
/*Output: http://localhost/project/project/index.php*/
?>
```

Comment: Quick tip: always follow up header(Location) calls with an exit otherwise the script will continue to execute, even if you don't see it. This could create security issues or vague bugs.

Comment: Thanks for heads up Erik. I just didn't do it for this code since there is nothing after the header. :)
But to avoid confusion I will edit it.